# Ubuntu 16.04 boot error (HP ProBook)

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 along side Windows 10, but then Windows 10 booting got messed up due to Ubuntu boot error. I then fully removed Windows and have installed Ubuntu. I am still having errors while booting on Ubuntu. I have tried Ubuntu boot repair. I wanted to know what BIOS settings I should use.  I am using HP ProBook.

1. Boot mode should be set to legacy, `uefi hybrid` or `uefi native`?
2. Any changes to be done in boot order?
3. Intel smart connect technology should be enabled or not?
4. Fast boot enabled?
5. Secure boot enabled?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying.

Comment: Installing 16.04

Comment: Please describe the error(s) you're seeing. Post screen shots (*legible* digital photos) or *complete* and *accurate* text from the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

while installing do you get a message that you are in UEFI and you will not able to launch the OS again in bios mode?
If you continued in UEFI mode you can't launch back windows 10?
Have you choosed the option to "continue in UEFI mode"